# Back-out plan for cumulative updates

Tags: backup, cumulative-update

I was wondering how your back-out plans look like. Untill now I must admit I never have had a really decent back-out plan in place when installing cumulative updates. I did ran into some issues sometimes, but usually those were fixable in a small amount of time inside of the outage window. But I would not have a good solution when the shit really hits the fan.

Theoretically speaking, would this suffice:

- Restore pre-upgrade SQL back-ups of all databases
- Restore pre-upgrade VM images of front-ends and back-ends

I cannot find a reason why it wouldn't, but since I haven't tried....

We're also running DocAve back-ups at the customer I'm at; but do those also revent SharePoint binaries? I assume they don't.

Answer (score 0):

CUs should be tested in a non-production environment before you consider installing them in production to make sure they do not have any major issues with your configuration and customizations.

The update process will update the binaries and then the database schema so rolling back is difficult.  Your best bet is to overcome the challenge of the install if at all possible.  If that is not possible, or if a major bug is introduced, then you are looking at a full DR.  That could be a Platform restore with AvePoint, or full OS/DB restores.